# Where in the SFDX tree do translations of quick actions go?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, quickaction, translation, translation-workbench

I'm failing to successfully Google where to put in the SFDX tree translations for the labels of quick actions e.g. `<label>Duplicate Account</label>` here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionSubtype>ScreenAction</actionSubtype>
    <description>Duplicates the Account and ...</description>
    <label>Duplicate Account</label>
    <lightningWebComponent>duplicateScreenAction</lightningWebComponent>
    <optionsCreateFeedItem>false</optionsCreateFeedItem>
    <type>LightningWebComponent</type>
</QuickAction>
```

located in the `quickActions` folder.

Where do translations of these labels go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The translations for QuickActions are included as part of the objectTranslation metadata. So for each object, you can include translations of quickActions as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <layouts>
        NameLayout
    </layouts>
    <quickActions>
        <aspect>Master</aspect>
        <label>デュプリケート</label>
        <name>Duplicate</name>
    </quickActions>
</CustomObjectTranslation>
```

Bear in mind it's the translation object metadata you want, named as follows:

`Object__c-ja.objectTranslation-meta.xml` where `ja` is the language, in this case Japanese.